# import packages error "Error in `python': free(): invalid pointer:" in Python 2.7 Anaconda 4

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda, ubuntu-16.04

I was using ubuntu 15 and it crashed. So I decided to take this opportunity to install the latest ubuntu 16. I installed python 2.7 Anaconda 4, and in my .bashrc, I added my source code path in export PYTHONPATH

```
export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:/my_program/src
```

When I run a python terminal, and type

```
import Main.Project
```

It shows the follow error messages which I have never encountered before. I tried switching to gcc 4 instead of the default 5 used in ubuntu 16, but it doesn't help.

Do you have idea why this occur? Thanks!

```
    Python 2.7.11 |Anaconda 4.0.0 (64-bit)| (default, Dec  6 2015, 18:08:32)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
>>> import Main.Project
*** Error in `python': free(): invalid pointer: 0x00007fd977add680 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x77725)[0x7fd99bffe725]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7ff4a)[0x7fd99c006f4a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x4c)[0x7fd99c00aabc]
/home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dynd/../../../libdyndt.so(_ZNSt6locale5_Impl16_M_install_facetEPKNS_2idEPKNS_5facetE+0x142)[0x7fd97783fab2]
/home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dynd/../../../libdyndt.so(_ZNSt6locale5_ImplC2Em+0x1e3)[0x7fd977832473]
/home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dynd/../../../libdyndt.so(_ZNSt6locale18_S_initialize_onceEv+0x15)[0x7fd9778333e5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0xead9)[0x7fd99ca6ead9]
/home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dynd/../../../libdyndt.so(_ZNSt6locale13_S_initializeEv+0x21)[0x7fd977833431]
/home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dynd/../../../libdyndt.so(_ZNSt6localeC1Ev+0x13)[0x7fd977833473]
/home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dynd/../../../libdyndt.so(_ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev+0xb4)[0x7fd9778306f4]
/home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dynd/../../../libdyndt.so(+0x72950)[0x7fd9777be950]
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2(+0x104ea)[0x7fd99d0744ea]
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2(+0x105fb)[0x7fd99d0745fb]
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2(+0x15712)[0x7fd99d079712]
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2(+0x10394)[0x7fd99d074394]
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2(+0x14bd9)[0x7fd99d078bd9]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2(+0xf09)[0x7fd99c85cf09]
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2(+0x10394)[0x7fd99d074394]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2(+0x1571)[0x7fd99c85d571]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2(dlopen+0x31)[0x7fd99c85cfa1]
/home/michael/anaconda2/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(_PyImport_GetDynLoadFunc+0x13e)[0x7fd99cdacdde]
/home/michael/anaconda2/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(_PyImport_LoadDynamicModule+0x98)[0x7fd99cd918d8]
/home/michael/anaconda2/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(+0x112f81)[0x7fd99cd8ff81]
/home/michael/anaconda2/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(+0x1131f4)[0x7fd99cd901f4]
/home/michael/anaconda2/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyImport_ImportModuleLevel+0x1f0)[0x7fd99cd90820]
/home/michael/anaconda2/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(+0xf314f)[0x7fd99cd7014f]
/home/michael/anaconda2/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyObject_Call+0x53)[0x7fd99ccc6d23]
/home/michael/anaconda2/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords+0x43)[0x7fd99cd70633]
/home/michael/anaconda2/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x3d6e)[0x7fd99cd7529e]
/home/michael/anaconda2/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x89e)[0x7fd99cd7aa2e]
/home/michael/anaconda2/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCode+0x32)[0x7fd99cd7ab42]
/home/michael/anaconda2/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyImport_ExecCodeModuleEx+0xc2)[0x7fd99cd8ca82]
/home/michael/anaconda2/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(+0x1121ce)[0x7fd99cd8f1ce]
/home/michael/anaconda2/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(+0x112a2a)[0x7fd99cd8fa2a]
/home/michael/anaconda2/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(+0x112f81)[0x7fd99cd8ff81]
/home/michael/anaconda2/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(+0x1131f4)[0x7fd99cd901f4]
/home/michael/anaconda2/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyImport_ImportModuleLevel+0x1f0)[0x7fd99cd90820]
/home/michael/anaconda2/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(+0xf314f)[0x7fd99cd7014f]
/home/michael/anaconda2/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyObject_Call+0x53)[0x7fd99ccc6d23]
/home/michael/anaconda2/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords+0x43)[0x7fd99cd70633]
/home/michael/anaconda2/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x3d6e)[0x7fd99cd7529e]
/home/michael/anaconda2/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x89e)[0x7fd99cd7aa2e]
/home/michael/anaconda2/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCode+0x32)[0x7fd99cd7ab42]
/home/michael/anaconda2/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyImport_ExecCodeModuleEx+0xc2)[0x7fd99cd8ca82]
/home/michael/anaconda2/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(+0x1121ce)[0x7fd99cd8f1ce]
/home/michael/anaconda2/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(+0x112f81)[0x7fd99cd8ff81]
/home/michael/anaconda2/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(+0x1131f4)[0x7fd99cd901f4]
/home/michael/anaconda2/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyImport_ImportModuleLevel+0x230)[0x7fd99cd90860]
/home/michael/anaconda2/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(+0xf314f)[0x7fd99cd7014f]
/home/michael/anaconda2/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyObject_Call+0x53)[0x7fd99ccc6d23]
/home/michael/anaconda2/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords+0x43)[0x7fd99cd70633]
/home/michael/anaconda2/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x3d6e)[0x7fd99cd7529e]
/home/michael/anaconda2/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x89e)[0x7fd99cd7aa2e]
/home/michael/anaconda2/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCode+0x32)[0x7fd99cd7ab42]
/home/michael/anaconda2/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyImport_ExecCodeModuleEx+0xc2)[0x7fd99cd8ca82]
/home/michael/anaconda2/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(+0x1121ce)[0x7fd99cd8f1ce]
/home/michael/anaconda2/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(+0x112a2a)[0x7fd99cd8fa2a]
/home/michael/anaconda2/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(+0x112f81)[0x7fd99cd8ff81]
/home/michael/anaconda2/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(+0x1131f4)[0x7fd99cd901f4]
/home/michael/anaconda2/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyImport_ImportModuleLevel+0x1f0)[0x7fd99cd90820]
/home/michael/anaconda2/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(+0xf314f)[0x7fd99cd7014f]
/home/michael/anaconda2/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyObject_Call+0x53)[0x7fd99ccc6d23]
/home/michael/anaconda2/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords+0x43)[0x7fd99cd70633]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1315687                            /home/michael/anaconda2/bin/python2.7
00600000-00601000 rw-p 00000000 08:01 1315687                            /home/michael/anaconda2/bin/python2.7
0161b000-0340c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7fd970000000-7fd970021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fd970021000-7fd974000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7fd97774c000-7fd9778bd000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1448723                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/libdyndt.so
7fd9778bd000-7fd977abd000 ---p 00171000 08:01 1448723                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/libdyndt.so
7fd977abd000-7fd977ac8000 r--p 00171000 08:01 1448723                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/libdyndt.so
7fd977ac8000-7fd977aca000 rw-p 0017c000 08:01 1448723                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/libdyndt.so
7fd977aca000-7fd977adf000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fd977adf000-7fd978c93000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1448722                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/libdynd.so
7fd978c93000-7fd978e92000 ---p 011b4000 08:01 1448722                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/libdynd.so
7fd978e92000-7fd978eb5000 r--p 011b3000 08:01 1448722                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/libdynd.so
7fd978eb5000-7fd978ec2000 rw-p 011d6000 08:01 1448722                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/libdynd.so
7fd978ec2000-7fd978ec8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fd978ec8000-7fd978edb000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1446101                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dynd/config.so
7fd978edb000-7fd9790db000 ---p 00013000 08:01 1446101                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dynd/config.so
7fd9790db000-7fd9790dc000 r--p 00013000 08:01 1446101                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dynd/config.so
7fd9790dc000-7fd9790dd000 rw-p 00014000 08:01 1446101                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dynd/config.so
7fd9790dd000-7fd97911d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fd97911d000-7fd979142000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1705665                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tables/indexesextension.so
7fd979142000-7fd979342000 ---p 00025000 08:01 1705665                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tables/indexesextension.so
7fd979342000-7fd979345000 rw-p 00025000 08:01 1705665                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tables/indexesextension.so
7fd979345000-7fd979386000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fd979386000-7fd97939b000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1705675                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tables/lrucacheextension.so
7fd97939b000-7fd97959a000 ---p 00015000 08:01 1705675                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tables/lrucacheextension.so
7fd97959a000-7fd97959d000 rw-p 00014000 08:01 1705675                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tables/lrucacheextension.so
7fd97959d000-7fd979601000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1705721                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tables/tableextension.so
7fd979601000-7fd979800000 ---p 00064000 08:01 1705721                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tables/tableextension.so
7fd979800000-7fd979807000 rw-p 00063000 08:01 1705721                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tables/tableextension.so
7fd979807000-7fd979849000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fd979849000-7fd979856000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1705672                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tables/linkextension.so
7fd979856000-7fd979a55000 ---p 0000d000 08:01 1705672                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tables/linkextension.so
7fd979a55000-7fd979a58000 rw-p 0000c000 08:01 1705672                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tables/linkextension.so
7fd979a58000-7fd979a98000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fd979a98000-7fd979b13000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1705656                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tables/hdf5extension.so
7fd979b13000-7fd979d13000 ---p 0007b000 08:01 1705656                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tables/hdf5extension.so
7fd979d13000-7fd979d1b000 rw-p 0007b000 08:01 1705656                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tables/hdf5extension.so
7fd979d1b000-7fd979d1e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fd979d1e000-7fd979d30000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1705624                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tables/_comp_bzip2.so
7fd979d30000-7fd979f2f000 ---p 00012000 08:01 1705624                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tables/_comp_bzip2.so
7fd979f2f000-7fd979f31000 rw-p 00011000 08:01 1705624                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tables/_comp_bzip2.so
7fd979f31000-7fd979f36000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1705625                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tables/_comp_lzo.so
7fd979f36000-7fd97a136000 ---p 00005000 08:01 1705625                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tables/_comp_lzo.so
7fd97a136000-7fd97a137000 rw-p 00005000 08:01 1705625                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tables/_comp_lzo.so
7fd97a137000-7fd97a1b7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fd97a1b7000-7fd97a21a000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1705838                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tables/utilsextension.so
7fd97a21a000-7fd97a41a000 ---p 00063000 08:01 1705838                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tables/utilsextension.so
7fd97a41a000-7fd97a422000 rw-p 00063000 08:01 1705838                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tables/utilsextension.so
7fd97a422000-7fd97a465000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fd97a465000-7fd97a499000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1317527                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/pyexpat.so
7fd97a499000-7fd97a699000 ---p 00034000 08:01 1317527                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/pyexpat.so
7fd97a699000-7fd97a69d000 rw-p 00034000 08:01 1317527                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/pyexpat.so
7fd97a69d000-7fd97a6dd000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fd97a6dd000-7fd97a6e8000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1317489                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_elementtree.so
7fd97a6e8000-7fd97a8e8000 ---p 0000b000 08:01 1317489                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_elementtree.so
7fd97a8e8000-7fd97a8e9000 rw-p 0000b000 08:01 1317489                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_elementtree.so
7fd97a8e9000-7fd97ac69000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fd97ac69000-7fd97ac7a000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1446827                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/h5l.so
7fd97ac7a000-7fd97ae7a000 ---p 00011000 08:01 1446827                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/h5l.so
7fd97ae7a000-7fd97ae7d000 rw-p 00011000 08:01 1446827                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/h5l.so
7fd97ae7d000-7fd97ae90000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1446828                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/h5o.so
7fd97ae90000-7fd97b090000 ---p 00013000 08:01 1446828                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/h5o.so
7fd97b090000-7fd97b094000 rw-p 00013000 08:01 1446828                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/h5o.so
7fd97b094000-7fd97b0d4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fd97b0d4000-7fd97b0db000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1446833                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/h5z.so
7fd97b0db000-7fd97b2da000 ---p 00007000 08:01 1446833                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/h5z.so
7fd97b2da000-7fd97b2dc000 rw-p 00006000 08:01 1446833                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/h5z.so
7fd97b2dc000-7fd97b2df000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1446824                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/h5fd.so
7fd97b2df000-7fd97b4df000 ---p 00003000 08:01 1446824                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/h5fd.so
7fd97b4df000-7fd97b4e0000 rw-p 00003000 08:01 1446824                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/h5fd.so
7fd97b4e0000-7fd97b4eb000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1446826                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/h5i.so
7fd97b4eb000-7fd97b6eb000 ---p 0000b000 08:01 1446826                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/h5i.so
7fd97b6eb000-7fd97b6ed000 rw-p 0000b000 08:01 1446826                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/h5i.so
7fd97b6ed000-7fd97b70c000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1446825                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/h5g.so
7fd97b70c000-7fd97b90b000 ---p 0001f000 08:01 1446825                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/h5g.so
7fd97b90b000-7fd97b90f000 rw-p 0001e000 08:01 1446825                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/h5g.so
7fd97b90f000-7fd97b927000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1446823                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/h5f.so
7fd97b927000-7fd97bb26000 ---p 00018000 08:01 1446823                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/h5f.so
7fd97bb26000-7fd97bb2a000 rw-p 00017000 08:01 1446823                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/h5f.so
7fd97bb2a000-7fd97bb38000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1446822                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/h5ds.so
7fd97bb38000-7fd97bd37000 ---p 0000e000 08:01 1446822                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/h5ds.so
7fd97bd37000-7fd97bd39000 rw-p 0000d000 08:01 1446822                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/h5ds.so
7fd97bd39000-7fd97bd4e000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1446821                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/h5d.so
7fd97bd4e000-7fd97bf4e000 ---p 00015000 08:01 1446821                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/h5d.so
7fd97bf4e000-7fd97bf51000 rw-p 00015000 08:01 1446821                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/h5d.so
7fd97bf51000-7fd97bf58000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1446816                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/_proxy.so
7fd97bf58000-7fd97c157000 ---p 00007000 08:01 1446816                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/_proxy.so
7fd97c157000-7fd97c158000 rw-p 00006000 08:01 1446816                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/_proxy.so
7fd97c158000-7fd97c198000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fd97c198000-7fd97c1a3000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1446820                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/h5ac.so
7fd97c1a3000-7fd97c3a3000 ---p 0000b000 08:01 1446820                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/h5ac.so
7fd97c3a3000-7fd97c3a4000 rw-p 0000b000 08:01 1446820                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/h5ac.so
7fd97c3a4000-7fd97c3d6000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1446829                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/h5p.so
7fd97c3d6000-7fd97c5d6000 ---p 00032000 08:01 1446829                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/h5p.so
7fd97c5d6000-7fd97c5de000 rw-p 00032000 08:01 1446829                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/h5p.so
7fd97c5de000-7fd97c5df000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fd97c5df000-7fd97c5f7000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1446831                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/h5s.so
7fd97c5f7000-7fd97c7f6000 ---p 00018000 08:01 1446831                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/h5s.so
7fd97c7f6000-7fd97c7fa000 rw-p 00017000 08:01 1446831                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/h5s.so
7fd97c7fa000-7fd97c815000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1446819                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/h5a.so
7fd97c815000-7fd97ca14000 ---p 0001b000 08:01 1446819                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/h5a.so
7fd97ca14000-7fd97ca18000 rw-p 0001a000 08:01 1446819                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/h5a.so
7fd97ca18000-7fd97ca2a000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1446818                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/h5.so
7fd97ca2a000-7fd97cc2a000 ---p 00012000 08:01 1446818                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/h5.so
7fd97cc2a000-7fd97cc2d000 rw-p 00012000 08:01 1446818                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/h5.so
7fd97cc2d000-7fd97cc36000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1446891                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/utils.so
7fd97cc36000-7fd97ce36000 ---p 00009000 08:01 1446891                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/utils.so
7fd97ce36000-7fd97ce37000 rw-p 00009000 08:01 1446891                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/utils.so
7fd97ce37000-7fd97ce8f000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1446832                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/h5t.so
7fd97ce8f000-7fd97d08e000 ---p 00058000 08:01 1446832                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/h5t.so
7fd97d08e000-7fd97d098000 rw-p 00057000 08:01 1446832                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/h5t.so
7fd97d098000-7fd97d099000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fd97d099000-7fd97d0b5000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1446817                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/defs.so
7fd97d0b5000-7fd97d2b5000 ---p 0001c000 08:01 1446817                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/defs.so
7fd97d2b5000-7fd97d2b7000 rw-p 0001c000 08:01 1446817                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/defs.so
7fd97d2b7000-7fd97d2d1000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1446815                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/_objects.so
7fd97d2d1000-7fd97d4d1000 ---p 0001a000 08:01 1446815                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/_objects.so
7fd97d4d1000-7fd97d4d4000 rw-p 0001a000 08:01 1446815                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/_objects.so
7fd97d4d4000-7fd97d4de000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1446830                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/h5r.so
7fd97d4de000-7fd97d6de000 ---p 0000a000 08:01 1446830                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/h5r.so
7fd97d6de000-7fd97d6e0000 rw-p 0000a000 08:01 1446830                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/h5r.so
7fd97d6e0000-7fd97d6ec000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1446790                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/_conv.so
7fd97d6ec000-7fd97d8ec000 ---p 0000c000 08:01 1446790                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/_conv.so
7fd97d8ec000-7fd97d8ed000 rw-p 0000c000 08:01 1446790                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/_conv.so
7fd97d8ed000-7fd97d8f4000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 4199048                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.23.so
7fd97d8f4000-7fd97daf3000 ---p 00007000 08:01 4199048                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.23.so
7fd97daf3000-7fd97daf4000 r--p 00006000 08:01 4199048                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.23.so
7fd97daf4000-7fd97daf5000 rw-p 00007000 08:01 4199048                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.23.so
7fd97daf5000-7fd97db11000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1447006                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/libhdf5_hl.so.10.0.1
7fd97db11000-7fd97dd11000 ---p 0001c000 08:01 1447006                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/libhdf5_hl.so.10.0.1
7fd97dd11000-7fd97dd12000 rw-p 0001c000 08:01 1447006                    /home/michael/anaconda2/lib/libhdf5_hl.so.10.0.1Aborted (core dumped)
```